# JSON RPC Java dzhuvinov - how to set username and password?

Tags: java, json, http, rpc, basic-authentication

I am using the Java library for JSON-RPC 2.0 from [dzhuvinov](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/json-rpc-2.0.html). I am having problems setting my username and password for [basic access authenticaition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) for the calls. My code looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    URL serverURL = null;
    try {
        serverURL = new URL("http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:18332/");

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return;
    }
     JSONRPC2Session mySession = new JSONRPC2Session(serverURL);
     String method = "getinfo";
     int requestID = 0;
     JSONRPC2Request request = new JSONRPC2Request(method, requestID);
     JSONRPC2Response response = null;
     try {
             response = mySession.send(request);

     } catch (JSONRPC2SessionException e) {
             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
             return;
     }
     if (response.indicatesSuccess())
        System.out.println(response.getResult());
    else
        System.out.println(response.getError().getMessage());
}
```

And I get a response of:

```
Network exception: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:18332/
```

Trying a similar code in Python I get a proper result:

```
access = jsonrpc.ServiceProxy("http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:18332/")
print access.getinfo()
```

How can I configure the basic access authentication for my JSON RPC calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final String rpcuser ="...";
final String rpcpassword ="...";

Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
      return new PasswordAuthentication (rpcuser, rpcpassword.toCharArray());
  }});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how library from 'dzhuvinov' deals with streams. But you can apply this code to perform basic authentication on HTTP-transport level opened by `URL` class.

```
URL url = new URL("http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:18332/");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
String userpass = rpcuser + ":" + rpcpassword;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
conn.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Full code can be found here http://engnick.blogspot.ru/2013/03/java-trac-rpc-and-json.html . I used this to perform JSON-RPC stuff to communicate with API of `Trac`.